# Reveal hidden form elements by modifying their display attribute

Tags: firefox

How can I make a bookmarklet for Firefox that shows form elements hidden by `display: none;`?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to set all `form` and related elements to be visible by altering the `display` attribute if necessary. You can do this with JavaScript and jQuery.

---

### [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Show Form Elements
// @namespace   http://igalvez.net
// @description Modifies form elements' display attributes to reveal them.
// @version     1.0
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var elements = ['form', 'input', 'textarea', 'label', 'fieldset', 'legend',
                'select', 'optgroup', 'option', 'button'];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    $(elements[i]).each(
        function()
        {
            $(this).show();
        }
    );
}
```

---

### Bookmarklet URL:

```
javascript:(function(e,a,g,h,f,c,b,d){if(!(f=e.jQuery)||g>f.fn.jquery||h(f)){c=a.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/"+g+"/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove()}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)}})(window,document,"1.3.2",function($,L){var%20elements=["form","input","textarea","label","fieldset","legend","select","optgroup","option","button"];for(var%20i=0;i<elements.length;i++){$(elements[i]).each(function(){$(this).show()})};});
```

*(Generated using [Ben Alman's jQuery Bookmarklet](http://benalman.com/code/test/jquery-run-code-bookmarklet/) tool)*